# How do I get proper output from fgets when called from a separate thread?

Tags: c, multithreading, fgets

I would like to read a file line by line in a thread that I have created, but for some reason, the result that I'm getting from fgets is just garbage. What is the cause of this problem and how would I go about fixing it?

Here is the problem area, which is contained in its own thread:

```
    FILE *orders = fopen("orders.txt","r");

    int numOrders;
    numOrders = getNumLines(orders);

    int orderLineSize = getMaxLineCount(orders);
    char Line[orderLineSize];


    fgets(Line,orderLineSize,orders); // This is the call that gives me a garbage output
    printf("Line is: %s\n",Line);
```

This is what is contained in `Line`: `;3+`. However, this changes every time I run the program

And this is what `orders.txt` contains:

```
"I Could Pee on This: And Other Poems by Cats"|7.49|1|HOUSING01
"Across Islands and Oceans"|1.99|1|SPORTS01
"Soul Surfer"|7.99|3|SPORTS01
"The Immortal Life of Henrietta Lacks"|8.91|4|POLITICS01
"The Handbuilt Home: 34 Simple Stylish and Budget-Friendly Woodworking Projects for    Every Room"|15.63|1|HOUSING01
"The History of Surfing"|31.5|2|SPORTS01
```

Here is getMaxLineCount:

```
int getMaxLineCount(FILE *filePtr)
{
    char c;
    int lineCount;
    int maxCount;
    lineCount = 0;
    maxCount = 0;
    while(c != EOF)
    {
            c = fgetc(filePtr);
            lineCount++;
            if((c == '\n') && (lineCount > maxCount))
            {
                    maxCount = lineCount;
                    lineCount = 0;
            }
    }

    rewind(filePtr);
    return maxCount;
}
```

getNumLines:

```
int getNumLines(FILE *filePtr)
{
    char c;
    int lineCount;
    int maxCount;
    lineCount = 0;
    maxCount = 0;

    int peopleCount;
    peopleCount = 0;
    while(c != EOF)
    {
            c = fgetc(filePtr);
            if(c == '\n')
                    peopleCount++;
    }

    rewind(filePtr);
    return peopleCount;
}
```

Comment: Code does not show `fopen()` was successful nor the return value from the `fgets()` call.  (nor the value of `orderLineSize`) Suggest checking those first.

Comment: I checked the two functions; fopen does not return null, but fgets does. Why would that happen? The file I'm trying to read definitely exists, and there is data inside it.

Comment: Show us the body of `getMaxLineCount()`.

Comment: Added it to the actual description

Comment: Is `orderLineSize` a small number like 0 or 1 or maybe < 0?

Comment: BTW, change `char c;` to `int c;` in `getMaxLineCount()` and change to `while((c != fgetc(filePtr)) != EOF)`

Comment: `getMaxLineCount()` is messed up more.  Change to `if(c == '\n') { if (lineCount > maxCount) maxCount = lineCount; lineCount = 0; }`

Comment: `char Line[orderLineSize];` should be `char Line[orderLineSize+1];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that `getMaxLineCount` is consuming the file, so you have to rewind it.

Before the call to `fgets`, try adding

```
rewind(orders);
```

Unless multiple threads are trying to read the same file, this issue should have nothing to do with threading.

Update: The following short program works fine for me.

Update2: I have fixed at least some of the undefined behavior mentioned by @chux.

Update3: by chux  changed to `size_t`.  Re-order to allow last line to be tested if longest.   Move `lineCount = 0;` (it had only happened when a new max was found.)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


size_t getMaxLineCount(FILE *filePtr)
{
    int c; // Changed `char` to int
    size_t lineCount;
    size_t maxCount;
    lineCount = 0;
    maxCount = 0;
    while(1)
    {
        c = fgetc(filePtr);
        if (c == EOF) break;
        lineCount++;
        if (c == '\n')
        {
          if (lineCount > maxCount) maxCount = lineCount;
          lineCount = 0;
        }
    }
    if (lineCount > maxCount) maxCount = lineCount;

    rewind(filePtr);
    return maxCount;
}

int main(){
    FILE *orders = fopen("orders.txt","r");

    size_t orderLineSize = getMaxLineCount(orders);
    char Line[orderLineSize+1]; // Extra space for the buffer.


    fgets(Line,orderLineSize,orders); // This works fine for me.
    printf("Line is: %s\n",Line);
}
```

Comment: I tried using rewind(orders), but fgets still gives me a null value. And I don't do anything with orders.txt until this part of my code.

Comment: @rafafan2010, Have you tried putting this code into a separate small test program to verify whether it works on its own?

Comment: I have, and I'm still getting the same result. fopen does not return a null value, but fgets does.

Comment: @rafafan2010, I'll try to reproduce and get back to you.

Comment: @rafafan2010, I could not reproduce your issue with the updated answer above, can you confirm that the code above gives you NULL on fgets, for the exact input you provided in your question?

Comment: UB in uninitialized `c` with `while(c != EOF)`.  `c` s/b `int` also.

Comment: @chux, Good catch. I will amend the answer with that fixed.

Comment: See my comments above - OP code has multiple problems.

Comment: @chux, Please feel free to edit the answer. Just verify that it actually runs at least on your box. I need to run in a few minutes and I doubt I will be able to fix all the possible problems with the OP's code.

Comment: @chux, I just put in the changes you suggested.

Comment: @merlin2011 I'm sorry, I missed something when I was creating the question. You're right, the code does work fine. However, I was having the problem occur when made a call to another function called getNumLines before that, and I think that's where the error is occurring. I'll post the function that is causing it; could you tell me what is wrong with it?

Comment: @merlin2011 I was able to use your revisions to get the program to work. Thanks for the help!